# How to emulate ntpdate -q with ntpd?

Tags: ntpd

From `man ntpdate` on a CentOS 7.2 server:

> ```
>    Disclaimer:  The functionality of this program is now available in the
>    ntpd program. See the -q command line option in  the  ntpd  -  Network
>    Time  Protocol (NTP) daemon page. After a suitable period of mourning,
>    the ntpdate program is to be retired from this distribution
> ```

From `man ntpd`:

> ```
>    -q      Exit the ntpd just after the first time the clock is set. This
>            behavior  mimics  that  of the ntpdate program, which is to be
>            retired. The -g and -x options can be used with  this  option.
>            Note: The kernel time discipline is disabled with this option.
> ```

This mimics the usual functionality of the `ntpdate` command.  However, `ntpdate` has its own `-q` flag as well:

> ```
>    -q      Query only - don't set the clock.
> ```

I don't see any way in the `ntpd` man page to perform this functionality.

Since `ntpdate` will eventually be retired, what is the future-compatible, preferred way to get the functionality that `ntpdate -q` currently provides?

Comment: Also, `ntpdate` appears to have been removed by default from Ubuntu between 14.04 and 16.04.

Comment: .What does the `ntpd --version` print? What OS?, please.

Comment: ping: Have you got an answer that works ?

Answer (score 2):

## query remote server

If what you want is to query a remote ntp server use:

```
# sntp 0.debian.pool.ntp.org
sntp 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Sun Feb 25 21:22:25 UTC 2018 (1)
2018-10-03 04:34:02.687911 (+0400) -0.002893 +/- 0.063203 0.debian.pool.ntp.org 186.118.171.89 s3 no-leap
```

## set ntpd time

If what you want is to set the server time:

With a recent version of ntpd:

```
# ntpd --version
ntpd 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Sun Feb 25 21:22:55 UTC 2018 (1)
```

The `-q` option will read as this in the manual:

> -q     Exit the ntpd just after the first time the clock is set. This behavior mimics that of the ntpdate program, which is to be retired. The -g and -x options can be used with this option. Note: The kernel time discipline is disabled with this option.

So, after stopping the ntp daemon (`service ntpd stop` or `systemctl stop ntp` depending on your system) use this command:

```
# ntpd -gq
```

The -gq tells the ntp daemon to correct the time regardless of the offset (g) and exit immediately (q) after setting the time.

Then, restart the `ntpd` and check that it is working:

```
# ntpq -pn
```

Comment: Thanks, but this answers a different question.  ntpdate -q does *not* set the time.  That’s what I’m asking to mimic.

Comment: Is the first option `sntp` what you are searching for?

Comment: `sntp` looks about right, but it isn't available from default repositories on CentOS/RHEL *or* Ubuntu.  So I'm sticking with `ntpdate` for now and I'll worry about the future deprecation/retirement when it comes.

Comment: @Wildcard Also found this https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?260785-ntpdate-deprecated

Answer (score 1):

`ntpdate` has been deprecated in CentOS for a very long time, but I have no idea when it's actually going to go away. With that said, you might want to take a look at the `sntp` package:

```
# sntp time.google.com
 3 Oct 01:11:30 sntp[6844]: Started sntp
2018-10-03 01:11:30.209781 (+0000) -0.000086 +/- 0.000366 secs
2018-10-03 01:11:30.221572 (+0000) -0.000130 +/- 0.000259 secs
```

*NOTE: the two results are because both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses were queried by default.*